# pronunciation: power

Tags: pronunciation

power /ˈpaʊə(r)/ ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/power)) 
[audio link](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/398)
Do you pronounce power's vowels in order of (1) -> (2) -> (3) or other ways?

[image: IPA chart]

Comment: Where did you get this diagram from? Moreover, there are only two vowels in "power," so why are referring to three vowels in the diagram? (I'm confused.)

Comment: @J.R. I added pronunciation marks from OALD, and the chart is from IPA on Wikipedia.

Comment: Are you asking because you think the dictionary may be mistaken?  If so, can you explain what made you think so?

Comment: I think I see what's going on here: when I say the first syllable of _power_ (i.e., the _pow_, rhymes with _cow_), the "ow" sound (represented by `aʊ`) requires me to make a shift with my mouth. In slow motion, it would start with the `pa` sound (as in "pal"), with my mouth open, and then my mouth would need to form a small 'o' with my lips, as I began to say the "w" sound (`ʊ`). So, the answer to your question is _yes_, I go 1-2-3 as you have diagrammed it. But this is a rather "advanced" way to look at vowel pronunciation; I think most natives do this without thinking about it.

Comment: Hey, but if you can learn to work this way, then it will really help you learn languages that have vowels that you didn't grow up with--and that's one of the hardest things to do.

And, yes, I also produce the sound as in your chart. Some of my relatives in Georgia just go 1-3, but that is *not* something you want to imitate! :-)

Comment: @Greg: I disagree. My guess is that in *most* contexts, *most* native speakers dispense with at least some elements of triphthongs like this. Obviously that's because even for native speakers, it's *relatively difficult* to clearly enunciate all the "potential" sounds. If you want to sound like a native, it makes sense to speak the way they actually do in normal speech, not try to emulate a "theoretical" pattern that normally only arises in contrived contexts where you're emphasising either the word itself or the "correct" pronunciation thereof.

Comment: ...admittedly I'm normally quite a "lazy" speaker, but personally I'd normally just go with **1-[next word]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I say the first syllable of “power” (i.e., the pow, rhymes with cow), the "ow" sound (represented by `aʊ`) requires me to make a shift with my mouth. In slow motion, it would start with the `pa` sound (as in "pal"), with my mouth open, and then my mouth would need to form a small 'o' with my lips, as I began to say the "w" sound (`ʊ`). So, the answer to your question is yes, I go 1-2-3 as you have diagrammed it. But this is a rather "advanced" way to look at vowel pronunciation; I think most natives do this without thinking about it.

([J.R](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r), [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/pronunciation-power#comment-15809))